# how to use for loop inside the switch case in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have speech recognition using switch case, and this is the code:

```
$scope.recog = function() {
    var recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
    recognition.onresult = function(event) {
    $scope.filteredItems = $filter('filter')(datauser['data']['friends'], {nama : search}, false);

    var result = event.results[0][0].transcript;
        switch(result){
        case 'login':
        $scope.loginFn();
            break;
        case 'sign up':
        $location.path('/register');
            break;
        case 'register':
        $scope.registerFn();
            break;
        case 'cancel':
        $scope.cancelregisterFn();
            break;
        //for (var i = 1; i < $scope.filteredItems.length; i++){
        case 'chat with friend number ' + i:
        $scope.chatWith(friend.userid , friend.nama);
            break;
        //}
        case 'go to home':
        $location.path('/home');
            break;
        case 'go to add friend':
        $location.path('/addfriend');
            break;
        case 'go to friend request':
        $location.path('/friendrequest');
            break;
        case 'go to pending request':
        $location.path('/penddingrequest');
            break;
        case 'add':
        $scope.addfriends();
            break;
        case 'send':
        $scope.sendMessage();
            break;
        default:
        alert(result);
        alert(i);
            break;
    };
    $scope.$apply()
    };
    recognition.start();
  };
```

but, I want to use `for` as loop in one case, as you can see I already made it as command, but when I delete the `//` it cannot work in my application. can I use for loop inside the switch case?
I use the loop is for like this:

```
for (var i = 1; i < $scope.filteredItems.length; i++){
            case 'chat with friend number ' + i:
            $scope.chatWith(friend.userid , friend.nama);
                break;
}
```

so, in the case i use `i` fron the loop. is it already detail?

**EDIT**

the `i` that I will use in case `'chat with friend number ' + i:` is the length of index from the friend list, and all user have different amount of friends, so I cant put exact number, like 5 or 6, I must use `i < $scope.filteredItems.length` for the total of friends.

Comment: Have you tried `case "something": for(...)`? [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/g2y648um/)

Comment: Break statement comes after the right curly brace. It breaks the for loop if it is inside it. So: `for(...) {... } break;`

Comment: Although I would rather export loop code to a function and call that. [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/g2y648um/1/). This will keep code clean.

Comment: *"can i use loop"* .. of course you can but you haven't provided any details what is is supposed to do or what problems are encountered when you do run it. Please read [ask] and provide proper details in the question

Comment: @Rajesh see my update again sir

Comment: @AleksandarBencun see my update again sir

Comment: @charlietfl see my update again sir

Comment: Can you share what exactly you are trying to achieve? You are trying to use `case` inside `for`, which is syntactically incorrect

Comment: @Rajesh done sir, I update my question again

Answer (score 1):

Based on comment that you are trying to create dynamic switch cases inside a loop that will not work.

What you could do is remove that whole scenario from `switch` something like:

```
if (result && result.indexOf('chat with friend number') > -1) {
  // do what is needed for this case with your loop

} else {
  switch (result) {
    // all the other cases shown
  }

}
```

Comment: what is result.indexOf for? can I just use `$scope.filteredItems` ?

Comment: @KhoirulZ IndexOf will return index of first character of matched string. So in this case, it will return 0 (starts with). If match is not found, indexOf will return -1. You can refer following post [String.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Comment: @Rajesh but how this indexOf is relate with the total of friends that user have?

Comment: It's not. This is to check if case is of this type. If you wish to check friends count, you will have to manually parse it. Refer my answer for that

Comment: It is simply  test to see if `"chat with friend number"` is in the string. You still need logic to handle which one it is if the condition is true

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```js
switch(result){
  case:
    .
    .
    .
  case default:
    var text = "chat with friend number";

    // Search if result is of type "chat with friend number" and find friend number.
    var friend_no = result.indexOf(text)>-1?parseInt(result.replace(text,'')):-1
    if(friend_no>-1){
      // do your stuff
    }
}
```

Note: above will evaluate all cases first. If probability of this is too high, you should try @charlietfl's approach.